# Hashmap procedure to resolve collisions

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashmap

Okay, so I have read alot about the `HashMap` lately and I think some people are making it a bit more confusing than it actually is. I want to know if this procedure is correct.

So when you have a `Key` and `Value`, for example *Peter Dirichlet* who is born *1805-02-13*, in this case the `Key` would be `"Peter Dirichlet"` and the `Value`, `"1805-02-13"`.

The first step would be to use the hash function on the `Key`, that is `"Peter Dirichlet"`. And let's say the hash function generates this to bucket nr `5`. That means that in that specific bucket, on index `5`, the Key/Value-pair `"Peter Dirichlet","1805-02-13"` will be stored.

So if we want to retrieve this information we use `get("Peter Dirichlet")` and the hash function will be used, the index number will be found and the Key/Value-pair Peter Dirichlet 1805-02-13 will be found.

And then we have the case of collision. Let's say we now have `"Leo Euler"` born `"1783-09-18"`. And for some reason our hash function puts precious Leo also in index number `5`. Since the Key-Value is **not** the same as Peter Dirichlet there will be no replacement.

Now, in "bucket" number five we have Leo Euler and Peter Dirichlet.
If we now want to  retrieve Leo, we use `get("Leo Euler")` and the hash function will point us to bucket number five. "*Woops*", says HashMap, "*here is a collision*".
Then we will iterate over these objects until we find `"Leo Euler".equals("Leo Euler")`. So it will get `key.equals(key)`?
So it will not we `true` for `"Peter Dirichlet"` but `true` for Leo and return the Key/Value pair.

Is this a correct interpretation of the `HashMap`?

Comment: Yes. The collision resolution in your case is chaining, but there are other possibilites for collision resolution (most importantly linear probing, quadratic probing).

Comment: Okay, will look in to that as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is the correct interpretation. The `.hashcode()` (for Java, equivalents for other programming languages) is not sufficient. It is possible that *collisions* happen. It will iterate through the bucket and for each element compare the query (a key) with the key of that key-value pair. Of course from the moment the correct key is found, its corresponding value is returned. In case the key cannot be found in the bucket, we know it is not in the hashmap.

That's why `.equals` and `.hashcode` have a contract with each other: if `a.equals(b)`, then the hashcode of `a` must be equal to `b`: `a.hashcode() == b.hashcode()`. Note that **the opposite is not true**: having the same hashcode does not imply that the objects are equivalent.

Perhaps a small remark on your question is that the internal array of a HashMap does not **consists out of key-value pairs**, it consists out of **collections** of key value pairs. In many cases this is either a `LinkedList` or an `ArrayList`. Some implementations use a binary search tree although in general it tends not to pay off much: after all using a good hash function should reduce the amount of collisions.